# Why isn't the xAxis showing the date?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a question related to HighCharts. Below is my code for implementing a highchart with integer values on yaxis and date on x-axis. I am getting my data from database both date and values.

The x-axis date and time isn't displayed correctly. In my database it looks like that ,2015-04-27 15:26:41.463 .

```
var a = [];
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                xAxis[0].setCategories(x);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: a
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: series
    }]
});
```

[image: Chart]

**UPDATE**

This is what I have reached now

```
    .success(function (point) {

    for (i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
        myDate[i] = point[i].date_time;
        value[i] = point[i].value_db;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < myDate.length; j++) {
        var temp = new Array(myDate[j], value[j]);
        mySeries[j] = temp;
    }
    DrawChart(mySeries, myDate, value);

})

function DrawChart(series, x, y) {
    //Fill chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            //tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: series
        }]
    });
}
```

[image: Chart2]

**UPDATE2**

[image: Chart3]

Help Please.

Comment: Your code doesn't nearly match the picture. Provide a live demo in http://jsfiddle.net if you can. By the way datetime doesn't work with categories. You are setting categories in xAxis. Instead you should  put your dates in **`series.data`** like this: **[[1430038718477, yourFirstData], [1430126796043, yourSecondData],...]**

Comment: @RaeenHashemi I have added an UPDATE section in the question showing extra code and a change of the previous following your advice, but the output is still weird though less. How can I get the right date and from where did the first point JAN appear ? I didnt mention anything in my code. Thanks for helping

Comment: As for jsfiddle I am not so experienced doing one especially since I have my own data not randomly generated or hard coded.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi I appreciate it if you can also tell me how to add more numbers on the yaxis for accuracy.

Comment: What does your **`point[i].date_time`** return?

Comment: Tell you what, give me your **`point`** array and I will make a demo of it.

Comment: point is data of type JSON so this returns my date in databse as is. I will run an alert message and add its image here

Comment: By the way the datetime should be in **`UTC`** format, so you should probably change the type of your datetime in the function.

Comment: Uhm there is something wrong from the data handling apparently..
point[0].date_time; gives Date(1430038718477)
point[0].value_db; gives 100

Comment: Try **`myDate[i] = Date.parse(point[i].date_time)`** and let me know what happens.

Comment: Is it string or just that?

Comment: It only gave that NaN

Comment: I mean **`Date(1430038718477)`** or **`"Date(1430038718477)"`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77065/discussion-between-raeen-hashemi-and-user2217303).

Comment: In the database there are three types: datetime, datetime2 and datetimeoffset. I am using datatime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change **`myDate[i] = point[i].date_time;`** to:

```
myDate[i] = parseInt((point[i].date_time).substring(6, 19));
```

So that it will contain the **`UTC`** date format of the datetime.

Then you will have to use **`xAxis.labels.formatter`** like this:

```
xAxis: { 
    labels: { 
        formatter: function() { 
            var date = new Date(this.value); 
            return date.getFullYear() + "-" +
                   date.getMonth() + "-" +
                   date.getDate() + " " +
                   date.getHours() + ":" +
                   date.getMinutes() + ":" +
                   date.getSeconds(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

to tell the chart how to show it's xAxis labels.

And for showing more labels in yAxis, you can use:

```
yAxis: { 
    tickInterval: 100 // if you want the labels to show every 100 values 
}
```

Comment: Instead of date.getFullYear etc, you can use [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)